# Проблемы с кодировкой в PHP форме

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

пытаюсь произвести поиск по БД, в которой хранятся данные на русском и украинском языках, в таблицах через phpnyadmin все выглядит красиво без "кракозябр" а вот сам запрос не выводит никаких результатов.

```
SELECT 
fi.film_name,
fi.film_format, 
fi.film_year, 
fi.film_id, 
group_concat(actor_name)
FROM film_info fi 
INNER JOIN film_actor USING(film_id) 
INNER JOIN actor_info USING(actor_id) 
WHERE fi.film_name LIKE {$search} GROUP BY film_id
```

в sql phpmyadmin такая схема работает, выводит по украинскому запросу все корректно, но с php var_dump() показывает пустой масив.
Попробывал просто вывести текст запроса, который передается БД, а там такое (см.скрин)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Значит проблема с тем как Эти данные из формы передаются в переменную, и как это исправить?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: База в юникоде?

Comment: База utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: У вас на скрине поисковая фраза «крокозяблами». Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо в настройках mysql кодировка по умолчанию не UTF-8.

Значит в вашем скрипте, перед выполнением запросов надо указать mysql, в какой кодировке будет работать скрипт, выполнив запрос:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема разрешилась, всё дело было в функции strtolower(), которая неадекватно ведет себя по отношению к кирилице. Заменив её на mb_strtolower() всё сразу же заработало. Спасибо добрым людям за помощь и извините за столь глупый вопрос!